# Many-worlds interpretation and the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, quantum-interpretations, eigenvalue

In Everett's Many-worlds Interpretation of QM, Schrodinger's equation is never violated (unlike in Copenhagen Interpretation). But how is this even possible? When you measure a system with respect to an observable $M$, the state of the system will turn into an eigenstate of $M$, which, may not necessarily be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, the evolution of which is given by Schrodinger's equation. Is this correct?

If so, how is it possible that Schrodinger's equation always holds regardless of measurement?

Comment: What do you mean by Schrödinger's equation is violated?

Comment: @NDewolf What I meant was the collapse of the wavefunction due to measurement. When you measure a system, according to the textbook QM, the system obeys the Born rule not the Schrodinger's equation.